# Animating dialog ::backdrop in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, dialog

I'm trying to make the ::backdrop pseudo-element of my dialog component using CSS. I've been able to achieve it on Edge and Chrome, but it seems like Firefox is not correctly applying the transition.

Does anyone know if that's not supported in FF, or my code is just wrong ? The modal itself respects the opacity transition, it's just the ::backdrop pseudo-element that comes up instantly.

This is the code I used for a quick proof of concept:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog')
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#openBtn')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#closeBtn')

openBtn.addEventListener('click', open)
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', close)


function open() {
  dialog.showModal()
  dialog.classList.add('active')
}

function close() {
  dialog.close()
  dialog.classList.remove('active')
}
```

```css
dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.2, 1) 2s;
}

dialog.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: black;
  transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.2, 1) 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

dialog.active::backdrop {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>test nice</p>
  <button id="closeBtn">close dialog</button>
</dialog>
<button id="openBtn">
  open dialog
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I checked - it seems that neither `transition` nor `animation` for `::backdrop` works in firefox.
As an alternative, I suggest set `box-shadow` to the `dialog`:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#openBtn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#closeBtn');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', open);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', close);
dialog.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if ( event.key === 'Escape' ){
    event.preventDefault();
    close();
  }
});

function open() {
  dialog.showModal();
  dialog.classList.add('active');
}

function close() {
  dialog.close();
  dialog.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.2, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

dialog.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>test nice</p>
  <button id="closeBtn">close dialog</button>
</dialog>
<button id="openBtn">
  open dialog
</button>
```

**P.S. If you want to have animation during closing `dialog`:**

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#openBtn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#closeBtn');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', open);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', close);
dialog.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if ( event.key === 'Escape' ){
        event.preventDefault();
        close();
    }
});

function open() {
  dialog.showModal();
  dialog.classList.add('active');
}

function close() {
  dialog.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; /* to prevent events during animation */
  dialog.classList.remove('active');
  setTimeout(() => {
      dialog.close();
    dialog.style.removeProperty('pointer-events')
  }, 2000); /* 2000 - is transition-duration in ms */
}
```

```css
dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.2, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

dialog.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>test nice</p>
  <button id="closeBtn">close dialog</button>
</dialog>
<button id="openBtn">
  open dialog
</button>
```

Comment: Worth noting that your examples only work if the close button is pressed. Pressing the escape button seems to break both examples.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Thanks for the comments. You are right... I will try to solve this problem when I have free time.

Comment: Your update works, thanks. FYI, you could also listen to [the `close` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/close_event). (I believe that compatibility grid is out of date/wrong. Listening and handling these events work the same on my android phone as they do on desktop browsers. I've reported this to MDN.)

Comment: @Kasper `::backdrop` is not a clickable element.

Comment: @imhvost You're 100% right, deleted my ignorant commend