# animating HTML dialog element backdrop on closing not working

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate the opening and closing of my dialog by using the new native feature where the display property can be animated. (The feature is explained towards the bottom [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#animating_dialogs:%7E:text=Supporting%20browsers%20animate%20display%20with%20a%20variation%20on%20the%20discrete%20animation%20type.%20Specifically%2C%20the%20browser%20will%20flip%20between%20none%20and%20another%20value%20of%20display%20so%20that%20the%20animated%20content%20is%20shown%20for%20the%20entire%20animation%20duration.)). Note that it is currently only supported in Chrome, Edge, and Opera as of now: [see caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_display_transitionable).

(!) Please Note: I realize I should use tricks like setting a close class with my animation and pairing it with an `onanimationend` eventlistener which then runs the `dialog.close()` method. My question is however NOT about that, and instead about getting the native display none animations to work.

As you can see from my snippet, I am able to animate the closing and opening of the dialog successfully. Even further the ::backdrop is successfully animating when opening the dialog. However, for some reason I do not understand, the ::backdrop is not animating when closing the dialog. Is this a bug with animating the display property? Or have I made a mistake?

I tried making another fade-out keyframe without the display values to use only for the backdrop but it still does'not work.

I suspect it has something to do with the descrete animation effect only working on the element itself and not children or pseudoelements, but I am not sure.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog")
const open = document.getElementById("open")
const close = document.getElementById("close")

open.onclick = () => dialog.showModal()
close.onclick = () => dialog.close()
```

```css
dialog {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: unset;
    inset: unset;
    width: unset;
    height: unset;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    animation: scale-out 1000ms forwards, fade-out 1000ms forwards;
}
dialog::backdrop {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    animation: test 1000ms forwards;
}

dialog[open] {
    animation: scale-in 1000ms forwards, fade-in 1000ms forwards;
}
dialog[open]::backdrop {
    animation: fade-in 1000ms forwards;
}

@keyframes test {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes scale-in {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes scale-out {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</dialog>

<button id="open">Open</button>
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745289/css-animation-when-closing-modal

Comment: @James what you linked-to has anything to do specifically with the `<dialog>` Element?

Comment: Just FYI, the modal overlay is not animating for me in Firefox. I would suggest that applying CSS to the overlay will be extremely browser-dependent. If you need this to function consistently across multiple browsers, you would probably be better off implementing your own dialog control where you will have full control over the UI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right, I added the caniuse table to the question and you can see it only works in chrome, edge and opera. I still am trying to get it to work for a hobby project though.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No!  However the top answer does mention using transitions instead of animations which I thought might be key here.  Since we are talking about using the transition-behavior property, seems like it would apply to a transition rather than an animation.

Comment: @James the MDN link I gave says: "When animating using CSS transitions, transition-behavior: allow-discrete needs to be set to enable the above behavior. This behavior is available by default when animating with CSS animations; an equivalent step is not required."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating dialog ::backdrop in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313685/animating-dialog-backdrop-in-firefox)

Comment: @imhvost Like Rory suggested I should, this would be one way of implementing my own dialog control where I have full control over the UI. But my question is about how I can achieve the animation using the new native feature for animating the display property

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to animate backdrop while closing dialog that it disappers in your case, i have tested this on edge as your concern is with google chrome, i agree with you.
So i can only ask you to try this much with your respective browser and hope that, this solve your issue. If not then let me know...

changes that made `only in css`:

```
dialog{
    /* rest piece of code */
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* updated */
    transition: 2s ease-out; /* added */
    /* rest piece of code */
}
```

- `box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset ;`
- In the code you provided, the box-shadow property is set to `0 0 0.5rem 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Here, `0 0` sets the **horizontal offset** and **vertical offset** of the shadow to `0`, respectively. `0.5rem` sets the **blur radius** of the shadow to `0.5rem`. `100vw` sets the **spread radius** of the shadow to `100vw`, which means that the shadow will extend to the full width of the viewport. `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)` sets the color of the shadow to translucent or semi-transparent black, i.e. nothing but, the color that you choose for box-shadow.

for more details pls visit [MDN css/box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: why `100vw` instead of getting the largest side of the viewport? `100vw` will not work on portrait.

Comment: 100vmax would be perfect for this. It would however require that you use for example 200vmax instead if you want to pair it with the scale-in animation.

Comment: Did I ask you to change the animation in CSS? I didn't say this, so how did you come to the conclusion that this will not work with scale in? I have tested this code in Microsoft Edge, as I have told you. As "Roko C. Bulijan" stated that this will not work with portrait, I have tested it as well and it works fine. I agree it's not excellent like the PC view, but it remains good with mobile or portrait. Furthermore, you can use @media for this issue if you really feel it's a problem. Hopefully, this will clarify your question.